# How can I use an anchor tag to submit a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the following anchor to submit a form with jquery to Spring.  How is this done?

```
<a target="" title="" class="" href="">Save</a>
```

I've tried this, where requestNew is my form:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
     $("#requestNew").submit(function(){
         $.post("../acctRequests", $("#requestNew").serialize());
      });
  });
 });
```

It doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are adding a new event handler; all you need to do is trigger the existing ones, and the browser's native functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
     $("#requestNew").submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Please use this

```
<a href="javascript:document.YOUR_FORM_NAME.submit()"> Submit</a>

<form name="YOUR_FORM_NAME" action="YOUR_ACTION_PAGE_URL" method=POST>
           <input type="text" name="YOUR_INPUT_NAME" value="YOUR_INPUT_VALUE"/>
      </form>
```

Replace "YOUR_ACTION_PAGE_URL" with your targeted action url

Answer (score 4):

Assign the submit handler outside the click. Then call it from the click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       // Binds the submit handler to the #requestNew form
   $("#requestNew").submit(function(){
        $.post("../acctRequests", $("#requestNew").serialize());
   });
   $("a").click(function(e) {
        $("#requestNew").submit(); // calls the submit handler
        e.preventDefault();  // Prevents the default behavior of the link
   });
});
```

Comment: This is the correct way. lonesomeway's answer (the accepted one) did not work with my browser as the default behavior of the anchor tag was not overidden, reloading the page, while subsequently losing post data.

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<form...>
    ...
    <a data-role="submit">Save</a>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-role=submit]").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="submit()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add an id to your anchor you can submit the form in your click function:

```
<a target="" title="" class="" href="" id="saveButton">Save</a>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#saveButton').click(function(){
    $("#requestNew").submit(); //if requestNew is the id of your form
  });
});
```

If you are trying to submit it with ajax that's a different solution but I'm not sure if that's what you want based on your question