# How Can I link My Styled Button With a Form?

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <form id="signup">

        <div class="inputs">

            <input type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus=""/>

            <input type="password" required="required" placeholder="Desired Password" />


            <a id="submit" onclick="confirmation()">REQUEST INVITE NOW</a>

        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: jQuery method http://stackoverflow.com/a/4674648/1586079

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a real submit input element `<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" />` then just use CSS to style the button using

```
input#submitbutton{
/*CSS GOES HERE*/
}
```

alternatively if you are not using an external style sheet add the CSS inside the HTML using something like `<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" style="CSS GOES HERE" />`

Answer (score 0):

What was posted isn't a button, just text with an event attached.  If you want a [submit] input to look similar see example `style=""` of code, tinker for desired effect.  This input will help you to pass the `<input type="email" />` and  `<input type="password" />` values. Use `name="email"` instead of `id="email"` attributes in the email, password, and submit inputs to get them to work.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus=""/>
      <input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="Desired Password" />
      <input type="submit" name="PICK-ME" value="REQUEST INVITE NOW" style="background: transparent; border-top: 0; border-right: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #333333; border-left: 0; color: #42413C; display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" />
    </form>
```