# Strange anchor tag behaviour

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, anchor

In my view im doing this :

```
<?php if($user_can_write) {?>
<a href=<?php echo base_url('backend_controllers/users/foo')?> style="text-decoration:none">
Add</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I pass variable $user_can_write from my controller , which is my implementation for access control, the **strange part** is whenever i refresh this page , ie this view , the anchor tag is executed , ie , the foo function in user controller is called and executed , every time !Basically the foo function increments the db by one row (adds row to the db), so this is really not practical for me that on every refresh the anchor tag executes

Now if i do this implementation in the view (alternate approach) :

```
<?php if($user_can_write) {?>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="on_click_method_for_anchor()" style="text-decoration:none">
Add</a>
<?php } ?>
```

and further in my javascript i do this :

```
function on_click_method_for_anchor(){
$.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('backend_controllers/user/foo'); ?>',            
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result){                
                $('.my_span_tag_class').html(result)
            }
        });
```

this seems to work perfect , and even if i reload the page , the foo is not called , can someone please tell me why is the **anchor tag behaving like this** ? am i missing out something obvious ?

Comment: do you have such script which call on document ready or body onload and execute a tag ?

Comment: yes @GBD i have script in document ready but none would cause a call to the foo function OR any function that would cause an insertion in my db , only foo does

Comment: moreover @GBD , if there is script in the document ready that causes the insertion in the db , why would it stop when i execute the alternate approach ?

Comment: it's hard to debug now. can you paste whole view source of your page on http://codepad.org/

Comment: @GBD aah , im sorry , sensitive code cant publish is , i modified the variables and stuff in the question , but i understand it would be difficult to debugg without it , thanks for the help , appreciated it

Comment: This is not directly related to the problem, but you should be aware that putting an action within an `<a>` link is not a best practice--you're taking an action via a GET call. Instead, you should create a hidden form and use jQuery to [submit it using a POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674625/how-can-i-use-an-anchor-tag-to-submit-a-form-with-jquery).

Comment: @JeffBowman i know ! but since it was my backend , i really dint bother about the POST and GET , the chances of tampering the request are impossible at the backend , so security wasnt my conern

Comment: @user1537158 I'm not addressing a security concern. Some clever browsers do funny things with GET requests, like cache them (so you never get called after the first click), or prefetch them (so you get called before the user clicks), or crawl them (such that a web crawler could accidentally add users). There's a remote chance that some internet accelerator plugin is prefetching that link for you, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: @JeffBowman hmm ooh ok , but i tried executing on firefox , IE and chrome with the same "strange" problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you miss the " " part just after href properties of anchor tag.

```
<?php if($user_can_write) {?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('backend_controllers/users/foo')?>" style="text-decoration:none">
Add</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Try this.
I think it will be ok