# A href onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, href

Hey I know its been asked before but those forums don't have the answer as per my code!

```
<a href="#"  class="button dark"
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" >Register</a>
```

In the code above it gives me an error Uncaught SyntaxError:

> Unexpected token ILLEGAL in thw chrome console.

It works perfectly using input type= button but in that case the predefined styles "dark button" don't work. I don't want to mess with the CSS so could anyone tell me how to fix this?

**P.S.** No the quotes don't have a problem, any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

UPDATE: the form code as well:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
                method="post" 
                name="registration_form">
                First name: (required)<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
                <br>
                Last name: (required) <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
                <br>
                Company: <input type="text" name="company" />
                <br>
                Contact number: <input type="text" name="contact" />
                <br>
                Username: <input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                id='username' /><br>
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
                <br>
                Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
                <br>
                Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <a href="javascript:regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);"  class="button dark"
                   value="Register" 
                   >Register</a> 
        </form>
```

Comment: are you sure the `a` element is placed in some `form` container? if not its `form` attribute should be assigned to some form name.

Comment: Yes its inside the form container

Comment: An `a` element isn't going to have a `.form` property, though your error message doesn't match the error you should be receiving.

Comment: @rushsangs I think you are trying to submit a form using anchor tag instead of submit button. Then you should check this [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6730314/1577396).

Comment: there is a high chance that `this.form` is undefined, because you reported an error in a comment like this ***Cannot read property 'username' of undefined***.

Comment: make sure this.form is defined, and each of the variable inside does not contain any illegal character.

Comment: Please share the rest of your form code.

Comment: @Mr_Green i tried putting my onclick function there, error again: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined And no i'm not using an anchor tag.. I've got a PHP code separately which takes this form information and performs some operations before submitting it..

Comment: @rushsangs why would you get that error when you are not even using `username` as I suggested in the link? I think you haven't tried it correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Cocococo this.form is defined as in? there is a form in the current page so that simply means its defined. The code works just fine with input type=button and onclick=regformhash.... but in that case i lose out on css

Comment: actually the `a` element does not have `form` attribute as well as property. Other input elements do have. So you should use the name of your form to access it. In this case you can also use `parentElement` instead (the `a` element is a direct child of the form element).

Comment: @KingKing yes that was it.. i called the form by its id and it worked! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this...

just pass the form and then access other fields in the function like this..

```
<a href="#"  class="button dark"
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(document.getElementById('myform')
                                  );" >Register</a>



 function regformhash(frm){
    alert(frm.username.value)
 return false;
    }
```

myform is ID of the form

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to submit the form using `anchor` tag instead of `submit` button.

Just replace your anchor tag element **completely** with this:

```
<a href="javascript:document['registration_form'].submit()" class="button dark" value="Register">Register</a>
```

No need of `regformhash()` function to submit the form.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730314/1577396)

Comment: I wasn't using anchor tag I was submitting my code through php after some injection preventions. But thanks the problem was just in the this.form attributes